# How to call present code inside a struct in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uiviewcontroller

I try to alert when something went wrong but i try to create alert i get error like this :
**Instance member 'present' of type 'UIViewController' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'SignUpViewController.FirebaseServices'**

How can i alert my users without this my way? Or any solution about my problem? I think my problem is about Struct. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage

extension SignUpViewController {
 
    struct SignUpModelFirebase {
        
        let emailText : String
        let passwordText : String
        let nameText : String
        let usernameText : String
        let profileImage : UIImage
       
    }
    
    struct FirebaseServices {
        
        static func createUser(user : SignUpModelFirebase, completion: @escaping(Error?) -> Void) {
        
            let storage  = Storage.storage()
            let storageReference = storage.reference()
            let mediaFolder = storageReference.child("Profile Image")
            
            if let data = user.profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                
                let uuidImg = UUID().uuidString
            
                let imageReference = mediaFolder.child("\(uuidImg)")
                imageReference.putData(data) { storageMetaData, error in
                    
                    if let error = error {
                        
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        present(alert, animated: true)
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                   
                    }else {
                        imageReference.downloadURL { url, error in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }else {
                                guard let imageURL = url?.absoluteString else {return}
                                print(imageURL)
                                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: user.emailText, password: user.passwordText) { data, error in
                                    
                                    guard let uid = data?.user.uid else {return}
                                    
                                   let data = [
                                    
                                    "email" : user.emailText,
                                    "username" : user.usernameText,
                                    "name" : user.nameText,
                                    "profileImageUrl" : imageURL,
                                    "uid" : uid
     
                                   ] as [String : Any]
                                    let firestoreDatabase =  Firestore.firestore()
                                    firestoreDatabase.collection("Users").document(uid).setData(data,completion: completion)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are creating Struct inside SignUpViewController?

Comment: otherwise i cant call present xcode gives me error "Cannot find 'present' in scope"

Comment: write self.present

Comment: still gettin error like this: 
Type 'FirebaseServices' has no member 'present'

Comment: It's not possible to show Alert here in struct. It's not a viewController. Return Error in createUser() function . Then show alert there from where you call thin createUser() function . example: completion(error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this all wrong. Your `FirebaseServices` struct should not be performing any user interface actions. It should only perform some logic and get data or return an error.

It is the caller (such as a view controller) of `FirebaseServices` that should handle the resulting data or error and update the UI as needed.

Remove the alert code from `FirebaseServices`. Simply pass the error back through the `createUser` completion block to the caller. Let the caller determine how to handle the error. That may or may not be the display of an alert.